# postgresql constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have table `projects` with column `(id[PK], name, parent_project)`

> parent_project column will be other project's id[PK].
>
> but parent_project cannot be itself.

What can I use in this case? `'check'` constraint?

Thanks

Comment: examples 

|id | name | parent_project| 
///
|1 | project_1 | 1| 

this is wrong case parent_project cannot be ifself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a foreign key constraint and a check constraint:

```
create table projects (
    projectid int generated always as identity,
    name . . . ,
    parent_projectid int,
    check (parent_projectid <> projectid),
    foreign key (parent_projectid) references projects(projectid)
);
```